# A PDF ran GetAdaptersAddresses. Should I be concerned?

Tags: malware, ip, phishing, pdf

I received and opened a PDF that ran:

- GetTickCount
- IsDebuggerPresent
- SetWindowsHookExW
- Sleep
- GetAdaptersAddresses

These are the 2 files it wrote:

- C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\UPnP Device Host\upnphost\udhisapi.dll
- C:\Windows\System32\Tasks\Microsoft\Windows\DiskDiagnostic\Microsoft-Windows-DiskDiagnosticDataCollector

This information is from VirusTotal. I also ran a PDF I created and got the above functions except GetAdaptersAddresses. **Why does a PDF need to run [GetAdaptersAddresses](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getadaptersaddresses)?** Note that VirusTotal did not mark the file as malicious.

I am also wondering whether SetWindowsHookExW can install a virus?

Any and all help will be appreciated,
A concerned user

Comment: Ask yourself, why would a benign PDF check whether or not a debugger is present or set Windows hooks, hm?

Comment: @MechMK1 That was my concern at first as well, but when I create a benign pdf with google docs and upload it to Virus Total, it also flags that the pdf checks whether debugger is present and sets windows hooks. I'm guessing this is standard pdf stuff? But maybe you can also do dodgy stuff with these calls? I am also wondering why it needs to get adapter addresses. For all I know, it's trying to connect to a printer? I don't know if that's how it works or not... maybe it is something malicious.